# How to go about running DirectShow.net application on other computers

Tags: c#, directshow, directshow.net

I have a C# DirectShow.Net application and i want to test it running on other computers in release mode. How can i go about making sure my program will run on other machines that don't incorporate the windows sdk and the filters it avails?

I will have to include the dirctshow dlls and such but what can i do about the filters themselves?

Update:
I have virtual machines to run it on, but moreover how can i make sure a certain directx filter is on a computer and if it isnt, grab the dll and register it to the computer from code?

Edit:
After i have the DLLs registered i run my program. It doesnt run, so i grab graphstudio and i attach my program's graphs to graphstudio and none of the filters are connected and when i try to manually connect them they refuse to connect.

Edit2:

```
Can you post more details about the scenario you are having problems with?
```

I am running my application which works on my windows 7 32bit machine on my Virtualbox VM. the virtualbox wont allow me access to my usb device for streaming purposes so i commented out the code that depends on it. when i run it, the filters wont connect. I did some testing and tried to recreate the graphs without the source and they wont connect together so that may actually be the problem.

```
OS version?
```

At the moment i am running the 32bit XP virtualbox VM

```
which filters you are using?
```

I am using

```
Source -> Smart tee (capture) -> GMFBridgeSinkFilter
          Smart tee (preview) -> AVI Decompressor -> Video REnderer

GMFBridgeSource -> ffdshow video encoder -> avi mux -> File writer
```

(w)riter has to be lowercase for some odd reason. dev machine has (w)riter and (W)riter

```
Which filters do you have there that you are not using?
```

Do you mean which are standard on the OS or filters i put in the code and am not connecting to?

```
You could also try with the original GraphEdit instead of GraphStudio, and you could debug your application remotely and see where it is failing exactly.
```

Graphedit only comes in the full windows sdk which is a pain to download where im at.

Comment: IMHO, the best approach is to use a Virtual Machine. You might not get the performance you expected, but you will be able to try different configurations and OS versions.

Comment: The SDK installs filters?  That's news to me.  Have you actually tried this?

Comment: tried what? i have my dev machine with 7 different windows sdk versions and i created an application incorporating directshow filters. I move the application to one of my virtual machines and after i register the corresponding DLLs (directshowlib, gmfbridge, ffdshow etc). I run the application but it will not run. I download graphstudio to view the program and none of the filters are connected and they wont connect even in graphstudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of a few verifications that you could do:

- As @HiperiX stated, it is a good idea
  to test your application in a clean
  system, maybe using some
  virtualization software. If you need
  to support Win XP, it will be a good
  idea to test it there too, since
  there are a few DirectShow filters
  that are only available in Win Vista
  and later.
- About the required filters, some of
  them might be provided by Windows.
  Those that are not, you must provide
  them and register them in the target
  system during the installation
  process of your application. I would
  recommend in this case creating an
  installation project from visual
  studio and attach all your
  dependencies dlls there. For a manual
  installation you can copy your
  filters to your application's folder
  and register them using `regsvr32
  filtername.ax` from command line.
- One more detail you will need to take
  care of is compatibility with 64 bits
  versions of Windows, since you cannot
  use filters built for 32bit native
  mode from a 64 bit applications. If
  your application was developped in
  .net and it was built using `AnyCPU`
  mode, the .net JIT will create 64 bit
  code from it and your 32 bit dlls
  will fail to load. So if you are
  using 32 bits dlls I would recommend
  building your .net application with
  CPU Type = X86. You can set this mode
  in your project configuration in
  Visual Studio.
- Depending on how your filters were
  created, you may also need to install
  [Visual c++ redistributable files](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=29).
- About this remark:

> I did some testing and tried to recreate the graphs without the source and they wont connect together

That is certainly a
   problem, you cannot create a graph
   without a source filter AND a
   destination filter. The source filter
   will in general determine the content
   format, compression, color space etc,
   etc. In order to test this
   application with a virtual system you
   need to provide direct access to your
   USB ports inside the virtualized OS
   and install the drivers for your
   capture devices there, as in a real
   system. Otherwise DirectShow will not
   detect your device(s).

Comment: is there a way i can run regsvr32 from code? I can do the manual install, but im sure somebody is going to get a hold of it and not know what to do and complain

Comment: @yms ok, would you know anything about my Edit: question update aswell?

Comment: Can you post more details about the scenario you are having problems with? OS version? which filters you are using? Which filters do you have there that you are not using? You could also try with the original GraphEdit instead of GraphStudio, and you could debug your application remotely and see where it is failing exactly.

Comment: updated, and i shall be messing with VM to make my usb work correctly to further test this

Comment: it does work on my VM. I had to install VS2010 for testing/debug. the VM changed the name of the device and i had to add ffmpeg and GMFbridge